# Meter JS update array document in mini - mongo

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, document

I want to delete or edit(update) fields in a Meteor JS client side (mini-mongo) collection. I can not get either a delete or update to work. I would like to update all of the fields in the selected sub-array with one call. Below is a sample of the data model:

```
{
"_id" : "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA",
"dailyWeightLbs" : 0,
"date" : ISODate("2014-01-09T05:00:00.000Z"),
"food" : {
    "alcohol" : 0,
    "beverage" : {
        "choice" : ""
    },
    "breakfast" : {
        "choice" : "",
        "detailchoices" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH",
                "ndbNo" : "18003",
                "shrtDesc" : "BAGELS,EGG",
                "water_g" : 144.116,
                "energ_Kcal" : 1010.88,
                "protein_g" : 36.062,
                "servingGmWt" : 184
            },
            {
                "_id" : "u3ki6ruxRp5HzsEus",
                "ndbNo" : "21005",
                "shrtDesc" : "BREAKFAST ITEMS,BISCUIT W/EGG&SAUSAGE",
                "water_g" : 144.116,
                "energ_Kcal" : 1010.88,
                "protein_g" : 36.062,
                "servingGmWt" : 324
        ]
  }
}
```

notice that food.breakfast.detailedchoices is an array of documents. The Collection is called Logs and has been published and subscribed to only show the current users data. I tried the following calls but none worked:

To update I want to replace the current subdocument in the first array element with a document with the same _id but different values:

```
revisedDetailchoices = {
                "_id" : "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH",
                "ndbNo" : "18003",
                "shrtDesc" : "BAGELS,EGG",
                "water_g" : 244.116,
                "energ_Kcal" : 2010.88,
                "protein_g" : 66.062,
                "servingGmWt" : 284
}

Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$set:{food:{breakfast:{detailedchoices:     revisedDetailchoices}}}});


Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {food:{breakfast:{$set: {detailedchoices: revisedDetailchoices}}}});
```

To Delete I tried:

```
obj{};
obj['food.breakfast.detailedchoices']   = {$elemMatch: {'_id':  Diet.foodData._id}    };
Logs.update("m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA", {$pull: obj});

Logs.update("m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA", {$pull: {"food.breakfast.detailedchoices._id": "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH"}}); 

Logs.update("m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA", findObject, {$pull: {food:{breakfast:{detailedchoices: {_id: "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH"}}}}});

Logs.update({'_id': "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA", 'food':{'breakfast':{'detailedchoices': {$elemMatch: {'_id':  "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH"} }}}};

Logs.update({'_id': "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA", 'food':{'breakfast':{'detailedchoices': {$elemMatch: {'_id':  Diet.foodData._id} }}}}, {food:{breakfast: {$pull: detailedchoices[0] }}});

Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$pull:{food:{breakfast:{detailedchoices: {$elemMatch: {'_id':  "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH"} }}}}});

Logs.update({"_id": "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$pull: {"food":{"breakfast":{"detailedchoices": {"_id": "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH"}}}}});
```

and a lot more. I have read the mongo db and meteor JS posts but can not seem to get the syntax right. Please help with an example or recommend a resturcture of my data if this just  does not work in Meteor JS. It seems like this should be a very basic example that should work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To Add a choice:

```
var newChoice = {
    "_id" : "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH",
    "ndbNo" : "18003",
    "shrtDesc" : "BAGELS,EGG",
    "water_g" : 244.116,
    "energ_Kcal" : 2010.88,
    "protein_g" : 66.062,
    "servingGmWt" : 284
}
Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$push: {"food.breakfast.detailchoices": newChoice}});
```

To Remove a choice:

```
Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$pull: {"food.breakfast.detailchoices": {_id: "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH"}}});
```

To Replace the choices

```
var newChoices = [{
    "_id" : "GWCPt7huXHm3QQ4oH",
    "ndbNo" : "18003",
    "shrtDesc" : "BAGELS,EGG",
    "water_g" : 244.116,
    "energ_Kcal" : 2010.88,
    "protein_g" : 66.062,
    "servingGmWt" : 284
}]
Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$set: {"food.breakfast.detailchoices": newChoices}});
```

To Remove all choices:

```
Logs.update({_id: "m9kqCv5szxxkpxzaA"}, {$unset: {"food.breakfast.detailchoices": true}});
```